# How to prove two methods are "similar"?

Tags: research-level, statistics, imaging

We are testing two imaging machines. One of the machines has been validated numerous times. However, we built the new machine and we need to prove that it is similar/comparable to the validated machine.

So, the machines image a certain tube and determine a physical property. With several image loops, we can find the same physical property, with slight variations, and obtain a standard deviation for the physical property for each machine.

We want to prove the similarity of the new method to the old method.

I have basic understanding of statistics. I tried to solve this by showing a large P value, just to realize that it is not sufficient proof.

Can we publish an article if we say that the two methods give the same order of magnitude results? Is this possible or do we need a clear statistical proof?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about general experimental procedure, not physics.

Comment: Where should this be posted then? Please be more constructive rather than inhibitory.

Comment: Experimental designs and results; this is clearly not off-topic.

Comment: As remarked, this is a soft-question, totally pertinent on this forum. Please reconsider...

Comment: In particle physics, part of the commissioning process for a new experiment is re-discovering at lot of known physics, and showing that these things can be recovered at similar or batter precision than the previous generation of experiments. But the details of what you do in that regard are heavily dependent on the details of the apparatus you're working on. From my point of view, the underlying question is fine, but as written this is too vague for any useful comment, and in it's current state I would vote to close it as "Too broad".

Comment: I would close this as off-topic because it is not clear what you are asking. When you say that "one machine has been validated numerous times", that means you already have a metric that needs to be applied and that is exactly what you need to do: apply the old metric to the new machine and publish the results of that.

Comment: Well, okay... for starters, soft questions are not on topic here. (With perhaps an occasional exception.) @yolo123 I would suggest that your latest comment makes it seem as though you are not as familiar with our scope as you think you are. In any case, I really do think that as written, this is too vague. Perhaps there is a good question for this site somewhere in there, but we'd need more details and clarifications to bring it out.

Comment: Now I understand why PhysicsForum has such bad reputation amongst all stackexchange websites...